# Beginner MySQL issues with invalid use of group function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been googling around and can't seem to find how to fix this. I'm currently using MySQL and am trying to run this

> SELECT song_id FROM ‘played_songs’ WHERE id=MAX(id)

When I run this, I get the error message

> ## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? For reference, I'm trying to get the latest row's song_id in a pre-existing database. The ID increments so the latest value is the max ID in the column. When I get that column, I would like to get it's song_id in that same row.

Sorry if this is a super basic question, I've never done this before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you can't use max in where clause, try this:

```
SELECT song_id FROM played_songs WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM played_songs)
```

but better solution is:

```
SELECT song_id FROM played_songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a "Having" instead of a "where". A Having is used when you are operating on a previous calculation (getting max id is a calculation mysql has to make). I would write like this.

```
SELECT song_id, MAX(id) as 
max_id FROM ‘played_songs’ 
HAVING max_id=id
```

Comment: The song_id returned will be indeterminate and unlikely to match the max_id. Also max_id = id should probably be max_id = song_id.